# QR Factorization: Size of Matrix R?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm reading about $QR$ factorization.  Here's what my book says:

If $M$ is an $n \times m$ matrix with linearly independent columns, then there is an $n \times m$ matrix $Q$ whose columns are orthonormal and an upper triangular matrix $R$ with positive diagonal entries s.t.:

$M = QR$

But how do we know what size $R$ is?

Since $Q$ is $n \times m$, I know $R$ must have $m$ rows for the product to make sense.  And I think "upper triangular only refers to square matrices, so $R$ must be $m \times m$?

Is that right?

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the laws of matrix multiplication, multiplying a matrix of size $a \times b$ by a matrix of size $b \times c$ produces a matrix of size $a \times c$.

In this case, from the dimensions of $Q$ you know that $a = n$ and $b = m$, and from the dimensions of $M$ you know that $a = n$ (check) and $c = m$. Therefore the dimensions of $R$ must be $b \times c$ = $m \times m$.

By the way, the usual convention is to say that matrices are $m$ by $n$, not $n$ by $m$.

Answer (score 2):

1. $R$ must be square for the reason you give.
2. If $R$ is $m\times k$ then the product $QR$ is $n\times k$.  But the product is $M$, which is $n\times m$.  So $k=m$.

Comment: Why couldn't a triangular matrix be rectangular? I've always seen definitions of $QR$ decomposition with $Q$ an orthogonal matrix (hence, square) and $R$ rectangular (if $M$ is rectangular). For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix. *Edit* The wikipedia article about triangular matrices says they are square matrices... Seems contradictory...

Comment: 1. You are responding to a post from over 2 years ago.  2. The usual definition of "triangular" applies only to square matrices, and the wiki link you provided calls those generalizations to non-square matrices by different names (e.g. thin qr factorization).